# How to implement Livedata and Databinding in Android?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I searched a lot about observable models and parameters but I got confused!

1-some of model extend from `BaseObservable` and set`notifyChange();` in setters and bind them for example to edittext like this: `app:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.getEmailTextWatcher}"` and that `notifyChange()` update text by changing `email` parameter of `user` model.

2-and some of them use `livedata` for observing and change UI in `onChanged()` method.
How can I use `liveData` and change UI by `databinding`? not by `onChanged()`.
and when `onChanged()` use while we can use `databinding` for UI changes?

**edited:**
here is my coded:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginResultCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    activityMainBinding.setViewModel(ViewModelProviders.of(this, new LoginViewModelFactory(this)).get(LoginViewModel.class));


}

@Override
public void onSuccess(String s) {
    Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onError(String s) {
    Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

and here is interface:

```
public interface LoginResultCallback {
void onSuccess(String s);
void onError(String s);
}
```

and here is User model:

```
public class User {

@NonNull
public String mEmail;

public User(@NonNull final String email, @NonNull final String password) {
    mEmail = email;
}

@NonNull
public String getEmail() {
    return mEmail;
}

public void setEmail(@NonNull final String email) {
    mEmail = email;
}

}
```

here is ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
public MutableLiveData<User> user = new MutableLiveData<>();
;
private LoginResultCallback mDataListener;

LoginViewModel(@NonNull final LoginResultCallback loginDataListener) {
    mDataListener = loginDataListener;
    if (user != null) {
          //help me fill here
    }
}

public TextWatcher getEmailTextWatcher() {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
         //help me fill here
        }
    };
}
}
```

here is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com......viewmodels.LoginViewModel" />

</data>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="test"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.user}" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.getEmailTextWatcher}" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{viewModel::onLoginClicked}"
            android:text="LOGIN" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

i just want to change `inEmail` edittext and upper edittext change by data binding

Comment: @pskink
model should declear in viewModel.how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, enable data binding in your app level `build.gradle` as follows:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Make sure you have `lifecycle` dependencies as well:

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$versions.lifecycle:1.1.1"
    ...
}
```

Now, let's say you have some `User` class:

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

Then, you could have some `UserLiveData`:

```
public class UserLiveData extends LiveData<User> {
    public UserLiveData() {
        setValue(new User());
    }
}
```

Here's a simple `UserViewModel`:

```
public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private UserLiveData liveData;

    public UserViewModel() {
        liveData = new UserLiveData();
    }

    public void observeLiveDate(LifecycleOwner owner,
                                  Observer<User> observer) {
        liveData.observe(owner, observer);
    }
}
```

Now, `activity_main.xml` defines layout with the user's first name `EditText` and `Button`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@={user.firstName}"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/load_button"
        android:text="Load"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*Please note* `@={user.firstName}`. It's needed for a 2-way data binding. Every time the user types something in the `EditText`, it's updated in the `User` object as well. Also, refresh the Gradle project so that to generate data binding files like.

In the end, `MainActivity` uses `ViewModel` to preserve bound `User` on config changes. So, you type something and rotate the screen, `EditText` will keep the text. Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private UserViewModel viewModel;
    private ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
                R.layout.activity_main);
        mainBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(UserViewModel.class);

        viewModel.observeLiveDate(this, user -> {
            // set initial User object
            mainBinding.setUser(user);
        });          
        mainBinding.loadButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // show the current first name 
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "first name : " + mainBinding.getUser().getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i got error on below lines in MainActivity:
 mainBinding.setUser(user);

mainBinding.loadButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "first name : " + mainBinding.getUser().getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

in setUser,loadButton,getUser
@Anatolii

Comment: @R.Abedi no problem. Did you sync the `Gradle` project?

Comment: @R.Abedi I fixed it - I accidentally put `show()` in the wrong place. The answer is updated.

Comment: thanks a lot.
i want to do another thing.if u can help me i appreciate that.

Comment: @R.Abedi You edited your question by adding the code. Originally, you were asking how to implement it in general. Anyways, what problem do you have with your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot.
@Anatolii 
I want to add textview to xml and update text when `user.firstname` change.but not settext in java.is that possible?
i try `android:text="@{user.firstName}"` but nothing change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178283/discussion-between-r-abedi-and-anatolii).

Comment: user should not be variable here as viewmodel is used ?

Comment: @ABDULRAHMAN could you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: observing liveData is a no go in a ViewModel